# LT Spice Automation and automatic Plot data extraction

Tags: ltspice, matlab

I am trying to automate LTspice from Matlab. I am running Lt spice netlist which is creating the .raw file. But I am unable to automatically extract the polt data after that. Any solution on how to extract the netlist output with Matlab or any other way except manually clicking export as .text?

Comment: You could set LTspice to save `.raw` files as ASCII (`-ascii`, command line switch), but, as the manual warns, that can be extremely slow, particularly for large simulations. I have never tried this myself. The `.raw` files are a mixed binary form, and there's a small utility, `ltsputil` (IIRC, in the Yahoo LTspice Groups), that processes `.raw` files for various reasons. Maybe this could be used in a small script?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a script to read the data of the `.raw` files. For Matlab, Ive used [ltspice2matlab](https://se.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23394-fast-import-of-compressed-binary-raw-files-created-with-ltspice-circuit-simulator). Alternatively, for users of Python, one alternative is [PySpicer](https://pypi.org/project/PyLTSpice/).

Answer (score 0):

You could use the measure command to print measured values of dedicated timepoints to the sim log

Google lists this: www.researchgate.net/publication/303987589_Import_LTspice_simulation_results_in_Matlab